# What does this Metal Gear Solid boot-screen depict?

Tags: video-games, object-identification, metal-gear-solid

[image]

This boot screen is seen at the start of the [Metal Gear Solid: HD Collection: PS Vita edition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTmePksjE7Y).

I can't make out what the picture is supposed to be.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of swapping out the hand-held image for an HD one that I found on MobyGames.

Comment: I liked this question. It was a thinker.

Answer (score 14):

**The picture is a composite close-up of two separate machines seen in the Metal Gear Solid franchise and found in the [HD Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Gear_Solid_HD_Collection)**

---

The top part of the picture is a close-up image of the front prong of the [Shagohod](https://metalgear.fandom.com/wiki/Shagohod) from *MGS3: Snake Eater*.

[image]

The bottom part of the picture is a close-up image of the arm of the [Metal Gear RAY](https://metalgear.fandom.com/wiki/Metal_Gear_RAY_(manned)) from *MGS2: Sons of Liberty*.

[image]

Comment: Very nice, even the camo pattern matches exactly!

Comment: I don't think the arm is rotated in the boot screen image. It's just the left arm rather than the right. Well answered otherwise though. +1

Comment: @LogicDictates - We were both wrong. They've flipped the image horizontally.

Comment: I was 'speaking' from an in-universe perspective, rather than an image-formatting perspective. In-universe, that's just the left arm.

Comment: @LogicDictates - Well, no. It's a picture that has been flipped horizontally. It's actually the right arm in-universe.

Comment: The only way that can true is if that's actually an image in-universe, which was flipped by one of the fictional characters living within that universe. If it's the actual physical arm in-universe, then it can't be the right arm, unless this is a hithertofore unseen version of Metal Gear Ray, which was constructed differently to all the ones we have seen.

Comment: @LogicDictates - If you zoom in on the writing on the top of the opposite arm, you'll find it reversed (mirrored), therefore the picture cannot be of an object that has total internal and external symmetry, in- or out-of-universe.

Comment: That proves it can't be the physical left arm in-universe, although it can't be the physical right arm in-universe either. That leaves us with two options: either it's literally a flipped image in-universe (doubtful), or it's just an image that's been flipped out-of-universe (which is certainly true, regardless of what applies in-universe).